# Subscription for a single month

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, synonyms

I am building a paid online tool where you can subscribe for one month without auto-renewal. If you want to use a tool again, you pay one more time.

Is such payment still called subscription, or is there a more precise word to call the payment and the according section in the menu?

Comment: One-month subscription is definitely in the lexicon

Comment: I feel like there should be a better term for it but I'm not sure there is. A one-time purchase is not a subscription. Auto-renewal is sort of the whole point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Subscription](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/subscription) means the right to receive something for a pre-arranged period of time typically for a prepayment.

While we usually assume it's an ongoing arrangement (e.g. month-to-month) it doesn't have to be.

Websites, by their nature, aren't episodic. So, subscriptions describe ongoing access.

Just as a *six-month subscription* would mean access for 6 months, a *one-month subscription* would mean access for one.

But, if you wish to remove ambiguity, you can always just call it a **one-month membership**.  To remove all ambiguity you can say in parentheses *non-renewing*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just a **"payment"** would be more precise in a case of a single payment for a month?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This answer is a bit sparse for what we normally prefer. I voted to let it stand, but many others would vote for deletion.